# Docker Compose run, how to map ports defined in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I am trying to run Django server inside a docker container, but the `localhost:port` is not working.

I tried to achieve this by running the following commands:

```
1. docker compose -p dev run --entrypoint /usr/bin/fish shop-backend
2. docker compose --project-name dev run -p8000:8000 --entrypoint /usr/bin/fish shop-backend 
3. docker-compose --project-name dev run --service-ports --entrypoint /usr/bin/fish shop-backend
```

and once I am inside the docker container I start the Django server using this command:

```
python3 src/manage.py runserver
```

but I am not able to reach the `localhost:8000`.

In shortcut my `docker-compose.yml` look like this:

```
...

services:
  shop-backend:
    container_name: ${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}-shop-backend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./:/app/
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "8000:8000" # HOST:CONTAINER
    depends_on:
      - shop-db
    env_file: .env.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}

...
```

Can you please provide some examples, of what I need to do to reach localhost:8000, if I want to run Django server from the docker container and get into the docker container I want to use the `docker compose run` command?

Comment: Use `docker-compose up`, not `run`.  You shouldn't need to "get into" the container.  (How would you "get into" a standalone `./manage.py runserver` process?)

Comment: "I am not able to reach" probably django is configured to listen only to 127.0.0.1 and because docker gives each container an isolated localhost device, it's not able to accept traffic from the host's network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of

```
python manage.py runserver
```

use this in your running container's bash

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

or you can add this command in your compose file to run on compose up

```
services:
  shop-backend:

    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000

    ...
```